# reactjs how can i read map in array on firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, dictionary

I have an array, and inside an array i have a map. Map has 2 value, title and content.

[image]

I want to read all values in array, but it should be like map.
I tried this code, but i can't do it. Can you help me?

```
{database.collection("notes")
          .doc(uid)
          .onSnapshot((doc) => {
            doc.data().notes.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <Note
                  key={index}
                  id={index}
                  title={value.title}
                  content={value.content}
                  onDelete={deleteNote}
                />
              );
            });
          })}
```

finally, it should be like this:
[image]

Comment: hi, i need help in creating react array map in firebase, can you please share source code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `onSnapshot` uses a `callback` that will be executed like Future. That means if you put that code in react and use `{}` around it it won't return anything.

To make it work use a state and `useEffect`. Your code could look like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "../../../github/ecronix/wc-csv-export/node_modules/@types/react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    database
      .collection("notes")
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        const tempList = [];
        doc.data().notes.map((value, index) => {
          tempList.push({ value, index });
        });

        setList(tempList);
      });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(({ value, index }) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={value.title}
            content={value.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```